# How to block a message in Microsoft Teams

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Now we plan to develop a data protection App for Microsoft Teams.
One feature is block a message when the message includes someone keyword.

Now we can use delegated permission and Teams itself http API(https://apac.msgapi.teams.microsoft.com/v1/users/ME/conversations//messages/?behavior=softDelete) to delete the message, but it not friendly to Teams Users, We try found a better method to implement it.

We found nothing but some similar production like McAfee and Smarsh released on [MS Office website](https://products.office.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/apps-integration-and-services) 
they have implemented block-message function, like below picture:

[the block message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPgP8.png)

Could someone tell us how to implement the function. Thanks very much.

Another, we do remove a chat participant by the same way. Is there any track to remove a chat participant directly

Comment: The API is not available as of now.

Answer (score 0):

The API is not available on Microsoft Graph. More information on the available APIs for Microsoft Teams can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

You could also have a look at DLP for Microsoft Teams here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/dlp-microsoft-teams#define-a-new-dlp-policy-for-microsoft-teams